# Using ajax global event to show loading image

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of problem with showing the loading image for all the ajax calls in the application.

**This is the way I tried (unsuccessfully)**

Front:

```
    <img src="~/Images/ajax-progress.gif" alt="" class="hide" id="ajaxProgress"/>
```

Css:

```
.hide{
    display:none !importent;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
 $('#ajaxProgress').bind('ajaxStart', function () {
    $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

});

When an ajax call is being made, the image is not shown.

why?

Comment: What do you think 'this' means inside the callacks

Comment: You also spelled 'important' wrong in your css class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this - it is custom namespace

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart.mine", function() {
   $('#ajaxProgress').removeClass('hide');
});

$(document).bind("ajaxStop.mine", function() {
    $('#ajaxProgress').addClass('hide');
});
```

or you can use this

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        $('#ajaxProgress').removeClass('hide');
    })
    .ajaxStop(function(){
        $('#ajaxProgress').addClass('hide');
    });
```

Comment: also tried that answer(the first block) and it didn't work, what does .mine in- ajaxStop.mine means? didn't saw it before

Comment: "mine" is your custom namespace, 'cause I have no idea if you have more AjaxStart/Stop functions binded, yet.

Comment: Ok, no i don't have any namespaces. and I used the second block of answer

Comment: Insert your CSS into your question please. Maybe you have problem there.

Comment: I inserted the css, I found out that !important is the issue.. and show() don't "pass" it. there is a way to pass it?

Comment: I thought that it will work but it didn't:) 
1) what is cssText? in $('.hide').css('cssText', 'display:none'); means?
2) i also tried  $('.hide').css("display", "none"); and then show the element in the console, but it didnt work.. the !important near none.. doesn't disappear.

Comment: i managed to solve it with:
$('#ajaxProgress').removeClass('hide');
and 
$('#ajaxProgress').addClass('hide');

Answer (score 2):

As of jQuery 1.8, the ajaxStart event can only be assigned to the document.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   $('#ajaxProgress').show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $('#ajaxProgress').hide();
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  Did you check the console to see if there are any errors occuring?  What does your CSS class "hide" do?  It might be overriding the inline style applied by .show()

Comment: i guess you right, ".hide" means display: none !important; 
i see in the inspector that it changes to display inline, but nothing is showing.

Comment: yes, that is the problem.  !important means that the display:none is taking precedence over the display:inline applied by the .show() function.  Create your own .invisible class which does display:none; and use that instead of the .hide class.